# I am not able to see the versions comparison in the version control (VS)

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

[Im supossed to see a comparison between the changes Ive done. (Im learning git)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d988V.png)
[This is What im expected to see , according to my instructor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mf6r1.png)

Comment: What you're looking at is generated by VS, not by Git itself. VS is just *using* Git here. If you want to learn *Git*, don't use Visual Studio; if you want to learn Visual Studio, do use Visual Studio. In any case, see also [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the comparisons. It means you went from an empty file to adding twelve lines. Whenever you see something highlighted in green and with a plus sign on the left, it means that you've added the line. If instead, it's a red line with a minus sign, it means you've removed the line.

Comment: Review the another Image I uploaded, just realized I could confuse people as I did with you. ( I only added the h1)

Comment: If you look closely on the right, you'll see that line 10 is highlighted in green and has a plus sign on the left. That means you've added the line since the last version.